# Nested directories managed by autofs?

Tags: debian, autofs

Is it ok to have nested directories managed by autofs?

e.g.

- `/nfs/zfs`
- `/nfs`

On my Debian 8 machine, I have `/etc/auto.zfs` like this:

```
repo -fstype=nfs,rw 192.168.0.2:/repo
```

and `/etc/auto.nfs` like this:

```
foo -fstype=nfs,rw 192.168.0.3:/foo
```

My /etc/auto.master.d/nfs.autofs then references these files like this:

```
/nfs/zfs /etc/auto.zfs
/nfs     /etc/auto.nfs
```

Is this supposed to work? Any caveat?

My main fear is that autofs somehow completely remove `/nfs/zfs` automatically at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question.

So apparently the correct way of doing this is through something called "multi-map" or "multiple-mount map", according to `man 5 autofs`.

<sarcasm>Oh such clear and predictable name.</sarcasm>

It's amazing that the words "nested" or "sub(-)director(y/ies)" do not appear at all in `man 5 autofs`.

Comment: Hi can you list the config you ended up using to actually do this? I'm trying to do the exact same thing and following the manpage's syntax for a multimap, but the "offset" (subdir? nested dir?) mount fails.